# TinyMCE wrong path after upload image

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, tinymce-4

TinyMCE version : 4.6.5

My form and tinyMCE editor is working on 'public_html/adm' direction and i'm trying to upload images to 'public_html/images/upload'.

tinyMCE init

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: '.mytextarea',
        plugins: 'advlist autolink link lists charmap print preview media textcolor hr table image code powerpaste',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent hr | link image table code ',
        powerpaste_word_import: "prompt",
        menubar: false,
        min_height: 300,
        entity_encoding : "raw",
        // enable title field in the Image dialog
        image_title: true, 
        // enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs
        automatic_uploads: true,
        // URL of our upload handler (for more details check: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url)
        images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
        // here we add custom filepicker only to Image dialog
        file_picker_types: 'image', 
.
.
.
```

postAcceptor.php

```
<?php

  $imageFolder = "../images/upload/";
  reset ($_FILES);
  $temp = current($_FILES);
  if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
   
    if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Invalid file name.");
        return;
    }
    if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Invalid extension.");
        return;
    }
    $filename = md5(date('YmdHis')).'.jpg';
    $file = $imageFolder.$filename;
    move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $file);
    echo json_encode(array('location' => $file));
  } else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error");
  }
?>
```

After i upload my image it appends on textarea like this.

```
<p><img title="logo.png" src="../images/upload/0a13617f5d569df6c616578df855c92a.jpg" alt="" width="335" height="292" /></p>
```

[image: texteditor]

The problem is my image is not render correctly unless i change image path like this.

```
<img title="logo.png" src="../../images/upload/0a13617f5d569df6c616578df855c92a.jpg" alt="" width="335" height="292" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `convert_urls: false,` option. That'll prevent adding `../`.

For example you tinyMCE init will look like this:

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: '.mytextarea',
        plugins: 'advlist autolink link lists charmap print preview media textcolor hr table image code powerpaste',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent hr | link image table code ',
        powerpaste_word_import: "prompt",
        menubar: false,
        min_height: 300,
        entity_encoding : "raw",
        // enable title field in the Image dialog
        image_title: true, 
        // enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs
        automatic_uploads: true,
        // URL of our upload handler (for more details check: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url)
        images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
        // here we add custom filepicker only to Image dialog
        file_picker_types: 'image', 
        convert_urls: false // <---- here it's added.
.
.
.
```

Source: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/#convert_urls

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `images_upload_base_path` configuration option to prepend URLs returned from the configured `images_upload_url`:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_base_path